# How can i determine the block size of an vxfs filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel

I am looking for a way to see what the current blocksize of an filesystem is.

Normaly i would use `tune2fs -l | grep "Block size"`, but that doesn't work on vxfs.
I googled a bit and found `fstyp -v /dev/vx/dsk/...` ([VxFS_Block_Size](http://wiki-ux.info/wiki/VxFS_Block_Size)), but there is no fstyp installed.

So now im wondering if there is something else to find out the block size of an vxfs filesystem.

System: VxFS on RHEL 5.8

Comment: Have you tried this: http://mkp.net/fstyp/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the blocksize by reading the superblock, thats what essentially the `fstyp -v /dev/vx/dsk/...` would be doing.

But as you say fstyp is not installed, there is alternative to read superblock.

```
fsdb -t vxfs /dev/vx/dsk/...
> 8192B.p S | grep bsize
bsize  1024 ...
```

PS: It is not really recommended to read the blocks of filesystem metadata with fsdb, if you unknowingly write anything to these blocks; fullfsck would be set and there would be fair chances of data corruption.

Answer (score -3):

Under Linux the full command is:

```
/opt/VRTS/bin/fstyp -v /dev/vx/dsk/group11/vol11
```

Comment: I already said that i found "fstyp -v /dev/vx/dsk/" and that i was looking if there is something else ...